# How to use Apache Cordova API in Ubuntu SDK

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch, ubuntu-sdk

I created an HTML5 app in Ubuntu-SDK. Therefore I went to New Project->Ubuntu->HTML5 App. The app is already working but now I wanted to use vibration to give the user a feedback to a certain keypress.

The only resource I found was this: https://developer.ubuntu.com/api/html5/sdk-14.04/org.apache.cordova.vibration/

But when I execute `cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.vibration` i get this back `Current working directory is not a Cordova-based project.`. And when I just use `navigator.notification.vibrate(2500);` nothing happens.

Can anybody help me how to access the cordova API?

The version of the Qt Creator is 3.1.1 (based on 5.2.1). The OS is Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 2):

In order to use the Cordova APIs you need to create a Cordova application as described here:

https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/apps/html-5/tutorials/cordova-camera-app-tutorial/

Cordova applications and their development flow are made so that they are as close as possible to what a Cordova developer is used to, and separate from the HTML5 application workflow from QtCreator for now.

The w3c vibration API (navigator.vibrate) should work out of the box though and this is currently a shortcoming in Oxide (our webview backend), I added a bug to track the issue here:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/oxide/+bug/1440863

Comment: thanks for your answer. But why so many different ways to do the same?